# why dosen`t refresh my view with new model after post ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a big problem..please help me.i have dropdown when value of it changed i want to fill some textbox.i write a action and return view with new values.but my page dosen`t refresh..this is my code please help me

```
       public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var varizeMoredi = new VarizeMorediModel();

        var settleTitles = db.SettleTitles.ToList();
        settleTitles.Insert(0, new SettleTitle() { ID = 0, Title = string.Empty });
        varizeMoredi.SettleTitles = new SelectList(settleTitles, "ID", "Title");

        return View("Create", varizeMoredi);
    }


    public ActionResult GetSettleTitleInfo(string customer, int settleTitleId)
    {
       // ModelState.Remove("BankAccountName");
        var varizeMorediModel = new VarizeMorediModel();
        var settleTitle = db.SettleTitles.Where(a => a.ID == settleTitleId).SingleOrDefault();
        varizeMorediModel.SettleTitle = settleTitle;
        varizeMorediModel.Price = settleTitle.Price.ToString("N0");
        varizeMorediModel.BankAccountName = settleTitle.BankAccount.Title;
        var settleTitles = db.SettleTitles.ToList();
        settleTitles.Insert(0, new SettleTitle() { ID = 0, Title = string.Empty });
        varizeMorediModel.SettleTitles = new SelectList(settleTitles, "ID", "Title", settleTitleId);

          return View("Create", varizeMorediModel);
        // return RedirectToAction("Create", varizeMorediModel);
        // return Json(new { result = varizeMorediModel });
        // var categoris = db.Categories.Where(m => m.Type1.Id == id).Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Title });
        // return Json(settleTitle, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {



    $("select#SettleTitleId").change(function (evt) {

      @*  var urlact = '@Url.Action("GetSettleTitleInfo")';
        var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';*@
        //alert(model);
        // alert(JSON.stringify(model));
        if ($("select#SettleTitleId").val() != "0") {

            var userElement = $('#@(Html.IdFor(m => m.Customer))');

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action( "GetSettleTitleInfo", "VarizeMoredi")',
                type: 'POST',
                //  datatype: "json",

                // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                data: {

                    customer: userElement.val(),
                    settleTitleId: $("select#SettleTitleId").val()//,

                },
                //success: function (data) {
                //    alert(data);

                //},







                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

why are you commented out the success attribute on the script portion, which is actually responsible for view change.

Comment: @@Sibashis thanks..but i don`t know how can in write in success?how can i get data in success?

Comment: you need to go through the jquery api for ajax post [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/], I think it will sort out your problem... btw sorry for the late response.